# Marking "visited" to javascript array elements presenting contradictory results

Tags: javascript, arrays

JS guys/gals! I had the impression that when using BFS in 2D arrays in JavaScript, we can directly mark "visited" on array elements like this: grid[i][j].visited = true, and then next time when we check grid[i][j].visited, it will return true. Here's a piece of sample code that works this way (feel free to run it):

```
var findP = function(origin, grid) {
var q = [origin], count = 0;
grid[origin[0]][origin[1]].visited = true;

var arr = [[0, -1], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [1, 0]];
while(q.length > 0) {
    var c = q.length;
    count++;
    while(c >= 0) {

        var t = q.shift();
        if (grid[t[0]][t[1]] === '#') {
            return count;
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            var m = t[0] + arr[i][0];
            if (m < 0 || m > grid.length - 1) {
                continue;
            }
            var n = t[1] + arr[i][1];
            if (n < 0 || n > grid[0].length - 1) {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[m][n] !== 'X' && !grid[m][n].visited) {
                grid[m][n].visited = true;
                q.push([m, n]);
            }
        }
        c--;
    }
}
return -1;
}
console.log(findP([1, 1],[['X','X','X','X','X'], ['X','*','X','O','X'],
         ['X','O','O','#','#'],['X','X','X','X','X']]))
```

The above code works fine. However, when I tried this, it doesn't work at all (infinite loop alert. won't be fun runnig it):

```
var shortestPath = function(arr) {
if (!arr || arr.length === 0) {
    return -1;
}
var i, j, hasBen = false;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] === '*') {
            hasBen = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasBen) {
        break;
    }
}
//(i, j) is where Ben is:
var steps = 0, helper = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]];
var q = [[i, j]], flag = false;
arr[i][j].visited = true;
console.log(arr[i][j].visited); // undefined
console.log(arr[0][0].visited); //undefined
while(q.length > 0) {
    var counter = q.length;
    steps++;
    while(counter > 0) {
        var temp = q.shift(); // temp = [i, j];
        for (var x = 0; x < helper.length; x++) {
            var t = helper[x];
            var m = temp[0] + t[0];
            var n = temp[1] + t[1];
            if (m < 0 || m >= arr[0].length || n < 0 || n >= arr.length) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!arr[m][n].visited) {
                arr[m][n].visited = true;
                    if (arr[m][n] === '#') {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (arr[m][n] !== 'X') {
                        q.push([m, n]);
                    }

                }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
        counter--;
    }
}
return flag ? steps : -1;
}
shortestPath([['*', 'O', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'X', '#', 'X']]);
```

The two console.log() in the above code both logs undefined, which leads to infinite loop. However, why the first code snippet works yet the second one doesn't? Aren't they the same when attaching .visited on array elements? I am so confused.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of **what** you are actually trying to accomplish, not just **how**? Your code is pretty hard to follow with all of the single-letter variables, lack of comments, and nested loops.

Comment: For the record, you cannot set properties on a string literal. You can, however on its' object wrapper. For example: `var x = "5"; x.visited = true; console.log(x.visited) // undefined`. However, if you say `var x = new String(5); x.visited = true; console.log(x.visited) // true`

Comment: @mhodges although my posted question is not related to the problem the code is solving,  here's problem description: you have 4 kinds of elements in a 2d array: '*', '#', 'X', 'O'. * is your starting point, # is your target end point. X is element you can NOT go through, O is element you can go through. find the shortest path from * to #. And my question is: how come in the first code snippet, I can use grid[x][y].visited = true whereas in the second snippet, arr[x][y].visited = true doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, after tinkering with the code a bit myself, I figured out what you were trying to do. If you `console.log(arr[x][y].visited)` in either example, it returns undefined. I will mess around with it some more throughout the day and see if I can get it figured out

Comment: I think I understand what's happening now. Thank you very much for pointing out we "cannot set properties on a string literal". I guess the first snippet works is the unusual thing, not the second snippet doesn't work.... I'll create a visited array to solve this problem. Thanks again!